# Extract words from txt file preceded by a seperator or blank space

Tags: c++, file, file-io, words

```
try
{
    CStdioFile file(_T("D:\\thedirectory\\1.txt"), CFile::modeRead);
    CString str,mainstr = _T("");

    while(file.ReadString(str))
    {
        mainstr += str;
        mainstr += _T("\r\n");
    }

    CWnd *editwindow = this->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2);
    editwindow->SetWindowText(mainstr);

}
catch(CException* e)
{
    MessageBox(_T("no such file"));
    e->Delete();

}
```

I have managed to read a .txt file, and then update an edit control box with the contents. works great, but now i want to extract only the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th word separately from the txt file. Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with std::ifstream ifs('n.txt'); while(!ifs.eof()) { std::string s; ifs >> s; /* do something with s here */ }  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
int i = 0;

while(file.ReadString(str))
{   
    i++;
    if (i == 1) {
        mainstr += str;
        mainstr += _T("\r\n");
    }
}
```

May be a good place to start experimenting. You can play with the value of i when intializing, placement of the initilizing variable, etc.

Comment: You're not incrementing `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *find* method from `CString` to find a "word separating" character, then use a substring method to extract the *word*.

Search StackOverflow for "CString parse" or "CString regular expression".